# Multiple errors when installing Angular CLI Ubuntu

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, angular-cli

I am trying to do the Angular tutorial listed on the Angular website, I've completed the first two steps (installing node.js and an npm client) and now I have to install the Angular CLI, this is where it goes wrong. According to the website I am supposed to install it by running "npm install -g @angular/cli" in my terminal, which I did. I then got a plethora of warnings and errors pertaining to certain nodes and showing what appear to be unfinished loading screens, followed finally by these errors:

```
npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /@angular/cli/chokidar/fsevents:
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.2.7
```

I've googled all of this and tried various solutions, but nothing worked.
These solutions included running the following set of commands:

```
npm install -g node-gyp
timeout 120 npm install -g @angular/cli > /dev/null
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

, trying to run everything as sudo (also didn't work)

I've found precisely one case online of a person experiencing the exact same issues I am, but a solution was not provided.

I am running Ubuntu 18.04.1, have nodejs v8.10.0, and npm 3.5.2

For reference, the tutorial can be found here: https://angular.io/guide/quickstart#step-1-install-the-angular-cli

Here is the full set of errors I encounter if i try to run "sudo npm install -g @angular/cli", if that helps to clear up what the problem is.

```
WARN engine @angular/cli@7.3.8: wanted: {"node":">= 8.9.0","npm":">= 5.5.1"} (current: {"node":"8.10.0","npm":"3.5.2"})
WARN engine @angular/cli@7.3.8: wanted: {"node":">= 8.9.0","npm":">= 5.5.1"} (culoadDep:symbol-observable ▌ ╢██████████░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░╟
WARN engine @schematics/update@0.13.8: wanted: {"node":">= 8.9.0","npm":">= 5.5.1"} (current: {"node":"8.10.0","npm":"3.5.2"})
WARN engine @schematics/angular@7.3.8: wanted: {"node":">= 8.9.0","npm":">= 5.5.1"} (current: {"node":"8.10.0","npm":"3.5.2"})
WARN engine @angular-devkit/schematics@7.3.8: wanted: {"node":">= 8.9.0","npm":"loadDep:symbol-observable ▀ ╢██████████░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░╟
WARN engine @angular-devkit/architect@0.13.8: wanted: {"node":">= 8.9.0","npm":"loadDep:symbol-observable ▌ ╢██████████░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░╟
WARN engine @angular-devkit/core@7.3.8: wanted: {"node":">= 8.9.0","npm":">= 5.5/usr/local/bin/ng -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng
/usr/local/lib
└── @angular/cli@7.3.8 

npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /@angular/cli/chokidar/fsevents:
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.2.7
```

As I am quite new to all this, I'm not really sure what this all means and so hope someone could help me, thanks.

Comment: They're warnings (they all helpfully start with `WARN`), not errors. Do you actually have a problem *using* the CLI? And if so, have you tried upgrading Node/NPM to meet the versions listed?

Comment: Hey, Ivan! Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you show us the version of your NPM client by running `npm --version`, as well as the version of NodeJS you're using by running `node --version`? Also, note that it's a _bad_ idea to run `npm` with `sudo` access - future commands may require you to run `sudo` with `npm`. (BTW, `fsevents` is a library meant for native access to macOS's FSEvents in NodeJS - https://www.npmjs.com/package/fsevents)

Comment: After installing angular-cli, you can run commands like ng new ? I think, that your installation is ok. If not, try installation with sudo.

Comment: You need to be on npm 5.5.1 or higher

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick responses! I haven't tried using the CLI yet (I do get errors when running it without sudo by the way) and the NodeJS and npm versions (as listed) are up-to-date, (I've just installed them for this tutorial), 8.10.0, 3.5.2 respectively.

Comment: That's not up-to-date, 8 is no longer even the latest LTS version.